# Overridden GWT CSS styles not being applied after deployment

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I'm currently developing a web application using GWT. For a specific view, I had to use the GWT DataGrid widget. Since I had trouble applying CSS styles to it, I decided to override the default style by re-inserting the specific style applied to its header and some other parts by fetching their names while inspecting the page.

This is what I put in my custom CSS style sheet :

```
.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridEvenRow {
    background-color: #444444 !important;
}
.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridEvenRowCell {
    border: 2px solid #4d4d4d !important;
}
.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridOddRowCell {
    border: 2px solid #4d4d4d !important;
}
.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridOddRow {
    background-color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridHeader {
    color: #aaaaaa !important;
    text-shadow: #4d4d4d 0px 0px 0 !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.com-google-gwt-resources-client-CommonResources-InlineBlockStyle-inlineBlock {
    background-color: #4d4d4d !important;
}
```

I know "!important" is supposed to be last resort and all and all but what's of note is that I've overridden the the default styles and it works great when I run my application in "Super Dev Mode".

The problem occurs when I deploy the .war file. Every custom style from my style sheet are applied correctly except for the ones I've overridden. The Chrome console shows no error when I load the page and those styles seem to be missing when I inspect the page.

Does anyone know what went wrong here and how to fix it? Please note that I'm not too familiar with web development and it's my first time coding a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem ist that the styles are not obfuscated in dev mod, so they will look like `.com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-DataGrid-Style-dataGridEvenRow`. When you compile and deploy a war file then all files are usually obfuscated and will look like `.GKY5KDJCI`.  so in production you are not overriding the styles.
you can change the obfuscation level in your gwt.xml file with the property:
`<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>`
other available options are: debug, stable, stable-shorttype, stable-notype. default is obfuscated.
anyway you should follow the apporach suggested by Youssef Lahoud and provide a custom css resource for your datagrid.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tobika! It didn't work with the "pretty" value for the class names' prefixes were still obfuscated, but it worked with the "stable" value! I'm guessing that Youssef's solution is better for security purposes, but I'm just working on a tool that will be used by my coworkers and will only be available inside our network.

Comment: its not only security but also performance. By using CssResource you are allwoing the compiler to minimize the css and reduce the initial loading time of your app. i recommend to use this style configuration only for testing purposes...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you style the DataGrid correctly using client bundle:

create a new css sheet called "DataGridPatch.css" for example and include the required classes like:

```
.dataGridHoveredRowCell{}
.dataGridHoveredRow {}
.dataGridOddRowCell {}
.dataGridEvenRowCell {}
.dataGridOddRow {}
.dataGridEvenRow {}
.dataGridSelectedRowCell {}
.dataGridCell {}
.dataGridSelectedRow {}
.dataGridHeader {}
```

Then create the interface:

```
public interface CustomDataGridStyle extends DataGrid.Style{}

public interface TableResources extends DataGrid.Resources {
       @Override
       @Source(value = {CustomDataGridStyle.DEFAULT_CSS, "DataGridPatch.css"})
       CustomDataGridStyle dataGridStyle();
}
```

and then simply instantiate the data grid as follows:

```
dataGrid = new DataGrid<Map<String, String>>(1, GWT.<TableResources> create(TableResources.class));
```